# How copy/paste text on BootToDocker console

Tags: console, boot2docker

I use Docker on Windows 8.1 and I would like know how I can copy/paste a simple text inside the Boot2Docker console please, I have try ctrl+v and right-click but don't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**1st Option**

```
 Right click on the window menu title --> Edit --> Paste
```

**2nd Option**

```
 - Double click the start.sh script (this is the script behind the boot2docker linkage)
 - Right click on the window menu title --> Options --> mark check box QuickEdit-Mode
 - You will then be able to paste text via right click
```

Answer (score 16):

1. Right click on top panel of Docker console -> Properties
   [image]
2. Click "QuickEdit Mode"
   [image]
3. Copy text and paste it by right click in Docker console

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that for me, doing so in default did not do the trick.
I had to go to Menu > Properties > set Quick Edit Mode ON.

Then, I was able to select text with mouse, to copy hitting "Enter" and to Paste with a right-click button on my mouse.

Pretty obvious things, but if you don't have those, it can be very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

you can 
 - paste by

> edit--> paste

- TO copy you can mark the "text" that you need, right click to

Answer (score 1):

If you want it default, click icon docker in terminal -> default -> click Quick Edit Mode

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10, Docker Desktop 4.0.1(68347)

I must tick like this and use ctrl+shift+C/V to copy/paste

[image]

Good luck!